# Query an popup/dialog in calabash android?

Tags: android, calabash, alertview

I see that you can query by alertview in ios but how do you query alerts in calabash android?

I want to validate to see if this alert exists, can I do so with `element_exists()`?

Answer (score 1):

It can be performed like:

```
wait_for_text("Notification message to be verified", timeout: 30)
```

This is an alternate way which partially serves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have used calabash long time ago, so, I'm not sure that calabash defined a step to check alert is showed or not. But, I think you can do a simple step that try to check a text (dialog title, dialog content...) or a button of dialog (OK,cancel...) is exists on alert. Hope the tips is helpful with you.